# Win32 Keyboard combination

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, keyboard

I need to combine the Alt + (Left Arrow, Right Arrow, Up Arrow, Down Arrow) keys to move the window in Win32.

Something like this, maybe?

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        if (GetKeyState(VK_MENU) < 0 && GetKeyState(VK_UP) < 0) {
        }
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: See WM_SYSKEYDOWN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the GetKeyState function during the processing of WM_SYSKEYDOWN messages.

```
case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
{
    if ( GetKeyState ( VK_MENU ) < 0 && GetKeyState ( VK_UP ) < 0 )
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: And which function do i have to use inside the parentheses?

Comment: I am no sure that I understand your question. Could you explain please? Your previous example is correct except the message type. You have to use WM_SYSKEYDOWN  to catch the moment when you click the ALT( system ) button.

Comment: I created a child window and I need to move it when i press the alt + arrows keys.

Comment: You can use SetWindowPos  for child window inside key handler.

Answer (score 0):

Note that VK_UP may come from Numeric Keypad while user is entering a character by its (uni)code position. Expected behaviour on Windows is that numeric character input works independently to the NumLock state. So you have to track this: React to Alt+Numpad input only after releasing Alt: If more than one key was entered so far, ignore it and let TranslateMessage() translate that to WM_CHAR (which is hopefully in your main message loop).